# How to refer to additional rows in GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

GridView has a header Row. There's Sub Headers. After this I have added another row to display some other data and this row is not `Header` type. This row is `Empty` type. Although it's defined empty, I need to show some data at Data Binding level (not within RowDataBinding though).

How can I refer to this 3rd row which isn't a data row?

A pseudo thought:

1. calling the controls in GridView.Controls ?

   ```
   GridViewRow vr = GridView2.Controls[0].Controls[2].FindControl("Header2GridRow") as GridViewRow;

               if (vr.RowType == DataControlRowType.EmptyDataRow)
   ```
2. foreach EmptyDataType row in GridView, then refer to g.row.cells[i]..?

Comment: Did you set the row as RowTemplate? Please share the layout of your grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess deleting questions would be something bad. So let me write the answer that works for me and logically/MSDN wise it seems right too...

Although we insert a GridViewRow as `EmptyDataRowType`, ultimately it becomes `DataRowType`. I also had to changed the way of referring to the GridView Control's existing controls' index

```
        GridViewRow vr = GridView2.Controls[0].Controls[2] as GridViewRow;

        if (vr.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        for(int i=0; i<=dtable.Columns.count;i++)
         {
            vr.Row[i].Text = dtableRow[i].ToString();
         }
```